# How to create Record class in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, record

I have the following class `Type`:

```
class Type{
    String type;
    public Type(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

I have few types initialised here:

```
Type cor = new Type("cor");
Type name = new Type("name")
```

and Now I want to have a class called `Record`,

```
class Record{
    String name;
    Type[] types;
    public Record(String name, Type[] types){
        this.name = name;
        this.types = types;
    }
}
```

Well I got stuck here. What I want to do is when initialise an instance of the class `Record`, like this:

```
Record rec = new Record("Position", ...);
```

it should be something like this, I will give an example of the position record here:

```
Record Position = [cor x, cor y, name z];
```

So is using Type[] a good choice here? I find it hard to both record the type and the variable name such as `x`, `y`;
Or should I use a HashMap?

Comment: What is the `Record` class trying to model? It currently seems like a container for arbitrary data types (and as such not very useful). Also, `Type` is only a wrapper around a named string; what should it be used for?

Comment: Uhh, `int` is a primitive type, not a Type type

Comment: I leave it just a wrapper here just to make this question clearer here. The problem is to both record the type instance and type name in the record class

Comment: Well, if you want a class that has both a type name and a variable name, you'll need to define a class that has a type name and a variable name (or a `Type` and a variable name), instead of `Type` which has just a type name.

Comment: You could make the class a generic {name, type, value} container, but I still don't see the big picture here.. e.g:  `public class Type<T> {
        String name;
        Class<T> clazz;
        T value;
        public Type(String name, Class<T> clazz, T value){
            this.name = name;
            this.clazz = clazz;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }`

Comment: This would allow you to create a "position" record that models coordinates `{0,0,0}` like `Record r = new Record("Position", new Type<?>[]
                {new Type<Integer>("x", int.class, 0),  
                 new Type<Integer>("y", int.class, 0), 
                 new Type<Integer>("z", int.class, 0)});`

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer the question without more information about what you are trying to model. Your 'position' example is fairly confusing as it implies that a single record has several 'variables' of different types. However I'm assuming that a record can have several types. It's unclear whether the types can change and whether there are a fixed set of types.

Ideally the set of types are static and you could use an enumeration of types:

```
enum RecordType {
    COR, NAME, ...;
}

class Record {
    public Record(String name, EnumSet<RecordType> types) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then creating a new record would look like:

```
Record record = new Record("My record", EnumSet.of(RecordType.NAME));
```

If the set of types aren't static then you will need to define a class. In that case I would recommend you use `Set<RecordType>` rather than `RecordType[]` as the constructor argument. This makes it clear that it is a set of types (i.e. no duplicates) and avoids all the error checking you'll need to do with an array.

If a single record can have several values for different types then you will need to have a `Map<RecordType,String>` member variable. In that case I would recommend against trying to define the values in the constructor. Instead have a `addTypeValue` method for adding values to the map.